# not geometric, not independent, kind of geometric probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

> Select a card from a standard deck *without* replacement until you get an ace.  Let $X$ denote the number of cards drawn prior to drawing the first ace.
>
> (a)  Find the probability distribution for $X$
>
> (b)  Use a spreadsheet program to display the probability distribution
>
> (c)  Calculate the mean and standard deviation for $X$.
>
> (d)  Compare these results to a geometric random variable with $p=4/52$.

So I started this question by drawing a tree diagram then building a table:

[image]

$\therefore \Pr(X=k)=\cfrac{P(48,k) \cdot P(4,1)}{P(52,k+1)}$ where P = Permutation Function=P(n,k)

Is there a quick way to calculate E[X] and Var[X] or should I use a computer to tabulate the values for X=0,...,48 and apply the general formulas?

Part (D) I get:

$\Pr(X=k)=(4/52) \cdot (48/52)^k$

$E[x]=(1-p)/p=12$

$Var[X]=(1-p)/p^2=156$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The probability calculation is of course correct. The mean and variance can be obtained by a mildly painful manipulation of binomial coefficients, or by *Indicator Random Variable* methods. Mean not bad, variance a bit painful. For general information on the negative hypergeometric (which is a slight generalization, waiting time until the $k$-th success) please see [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution)

Comment: Thanks Andre.  Had you posted your comment as answer, I would have closed it and given you credit!

Comment: It's OK, the important thing is that you have the relevant information. The most useful thing to you is probably the name of the distribution.